# CIAreaMaximum always return RGB(255,255,255)

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-image

I attempted to detect major color by CIAreaMaximum. But I can only get the white color(rgb:255,255,255) as a result no matter whatever picture I input. Do I misunderstand the function of CIAreaMaximum? Any help will be appreciated.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let img = UIImage(named: "leaf") ?? UIImage()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: img)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            
            Text("max")
            Color(uiColor: img.maxColor ?? .systemPink)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .border(.red)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    var maxColor: UIColor? {
        guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: self) else { return nil }
        let extentVector = CIVector(x: inputImage.extent.origin.x, y: inputImage.extent.origin.y, z: inputImage.extent.size.width, w: inputImage.extent.size.height)
        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaMaximum", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey: extentVector]) else { return nil }
        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
        var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
        let context = CIContext(options: [.workingColorSpace: kCFNull as Any])
        context.render(outputImage, toBitmap: &bitmap, rowBytes: 4, bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: nil)
        print("rgba",bitmap[0],bitmap[1],bitmap[2],bitmap[3])
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(bitmap[0])/255, green: CGFloat(bitmap[1])/255, blue: CGFloat(bitmap[2])/255, alpha: CGFloat(bitmap[3])/255)
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want the [CIKMeans](https://cifilter.io/CIKMeans/) filter added in iOS 13.

Comment: @HangarRash thank you for your comment. BTW, is there any sample code on how to use the return value of this filter? The link says it creates a palette of the most common colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CIAreaMaximum` filter will calculate the maximum value *per channel* separately. That means, if you have a red, a blue, and a green pixel in your image, the result will be a white pixel.

If you want to find the most common color in the image, you can use the `CIKMeans` filter for that, as @HangarRash pointed out. Just set the `count` parameter to `1` to only get one color.

The `outputImage` of `CIKMeans` will be of size `count x 1`, with each pixel representing a major color in your input. So if you want to get two major colors, you can set `count` to `2` and increase your `bitmap` array size from 4 to 8. You also need to adjust `rowBytes` and `bounds` in the `render` call accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use our small [CoreImageExtensions package](https://github.com/DigitalMasterpieces/CoreImageExtensions) to read the colors like that:

```
let majorColors = context.readFloat32PixelValue(from: outputImage, in: outputImage.extent)
let majorUIColors = majorColors.map { UIColor(red: $0.r, green: $0.g, blue: $0.b, alpha: $0.a }
```

I can also recommend downloading the free app [Filter Magic](https://apps.apple.com/app/filter-magic/id1594986951) on the Mac App Store and use it to experiment with the various filters and their parameters.

Comment: thank you for your recommendation.  I download the app, and it's quite useful and convenient to observe the filter effect. As for CIAreaMaximum,  does it mean it will fetch the maximum value of each channel, and compose them together to form another new pixel, instead of selecting an existing pixel? If I want to use CIKMeans, and set the count parameter to 2, could I also get 2 major colors then? Do you have some examples? I can't find any detailed documentation.

Comment: @test1229 I amended my answer with more details.

Comment: And yes, `CIAreaMaximum` will collect the maxima of each channel separately and will return them in one pixel. That's why it can't be used to find the major color, only major color _components_.